# How to check if a directive or controller is available in a module using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angularjs, given a module, how do you check if a directive/controller exists given a module.

I have a module and I want to know if some particular directives have been loaded. Below is some sample code:

```
var module = angular.module('myModule');
//check if controller exists
if (module.hasController('my.first.controller')){
   //do something
}
if (module.hasDirective('my.first.directive')){
   //do something
}
```

I have implemented this in a way. Looking for a better way of doing it if it is available by default.

Is this possible?
If so, how do you do this?

Comment: Do you want to find out those controllers / directives during the module's configuration phase? Or after an application was bootstrapped  (run()) phase was executed)?

Comment: Any will do for me. In any case, before I do the check, the application would have been bootstrapped using <code>angular.bootstrap(el,[myModule])</code>

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use this code to check if a service exists.

`$injector.has('myServiceName')`

To check if a directive exists, you must add a `Directive` suffix after the directive name:

`$injector.has('myDirectiveNameDirective')`

Answer (score 3):

I found some working code [here](http://www.tech.theplayhub.com/how_to_check_if_an_angularjs_controller_has_been_defined/)

```
angular.service('ControllerChecker', ['$controller', function($controller) {
    return {
        exists: function(controllerName) {
            if(typeof window[controllerName] == 'function') {
                return true;
            }
            try {
                $controller(controllerName);
                return true;
            } catch (error) {
                return !(error instanceof TypeError);
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fracz/HB7LU/6780/

Answer (score 2):

```
    var controllers = [];

    _.each(app._invokeQueue, function(value, index) {
        if (value[0] !== '$controllerProvider') {
            return;
        }

        controllers.push(value[2][0]);
    });

    if (controllers.indexOf('controller-i-want') === - 1) {
        // controller is undefined
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Solved the problem by writing a wrapper function that is called to load the controllers and stuff and at such I'm able to tell when each directive is loaded.