# ng-dropdown-multiselect library not working for me

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, ng-dropdown-multiselect

I found this cool library to do dropdown menus with [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) + [twitter-bootstrap-3](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-3), here:
http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/docs.

I am following the examples, I have this in my [html](/questions/tagged/html):

```
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="stringData" selected-model="stringModel" extra-settings="stringSettings">
</div>
```

And this in my controller:

```
$scope.stringData = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

$scope.stringModel = [];

$scope.stringSettings = {
  template: '{{option}}',
  smartButtonTextConverter: function(skip, option) {
    return option;
  },
};
```

And yet, absolutely nothing is being rendered to the page. :(

Anybody have any idea what might be wrong?

I have [twitter-bootstrap-3](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-3), [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) and [ng-dropdown-multiselect](/questions/tagged/ng-dropdown-multiselect) loaded in this order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/dist/src/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Chrome console? Press F12 and tell me what you see there.

Comment: this is for work, and so I unfortunately can't give you screenshots, but I can verify that there is no stdout/stderr output in the chrome console.

Comment: that's the problem, I really have no idea what might be wrong

Comment: maybe I should check to see if the directive exists at all - maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544125/how-to-check-if-a-directive-or-controller-is-available-in-a-module-using-angular

Comment: Or if any dependency is missing in the module.

Comment: I tried this, and it's false => `const hasDirective = $injector.has('ngDropdownMultiselectDirective');`

Comment: The directive says it depends only on Bootstrap v3 and AngularJS > 1.5, which I have satisfied.

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue through https://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: yeah I will reproduce tomorrow, running out of energy tonight, thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158914/discussion-between-danny-fardy-jhonston-bermudez-and-olegzandr).

Comment: ughh, I think I need to register the directive here: `angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngCsv', 'ngFlash']);`...I forgot about that lol

Comment: I added an answer with a new error trace...

Answer (score 2):

When I add the dependency here:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ngDropdownMultiselect']);
```

I get this error:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngDropdownMultiselect due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngDropdownMultiselect' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/nomod?p0=ngDropdownMultiselect
```

So I checked the docs (again), and it says to use this instead

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']);
```

now it "works"

ughh, gotta love front-end development lol

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ui.select',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.jq',
    'app.directive.voucherView',
    'abp'
]).filter('angularjs-dropdown-multiselect', function () { });
```